# fosuserbundle not loggin int PRO mode

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem for logging users in production

I have my secutiry.yml file as follows :

```
security:
encoders:
FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

firewalls:
main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:                                                                                                                                                            
            # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider                                                                                                                                                                                            

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/js, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/css, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and part of my config.yml:

```
  # Doctrine Configuration                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
host:     mysql-paradasym85.alwaysdata.net
port:     3306
dbname:   paradasym85_symfony
user:     user
password: pass123456 (fake)
charset:  UTF8
# if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:                                                                                                                                                                                         
#   1. add the path in parameters.yml                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"                                                                                                                                                                            
#   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist                                                                                                                                                                                  
    #   3. Uncomment next line:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    #     path:     "%database_path%"                                                                                                                                                                                                      

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
```

everything works properly in development but not in production mode

It seems as if / login_check not working.

a greeting.

Comment: i check version php and server and dev they have the same version

Comment: please fix the indentation of your code. What means it does not work "in production mode" ... `app/console server:run --env=dev` works but `app/console server:run --env=prod` does not? Did you clear the cache `app/console cache:clear --env=prod` ?

Comment: thanks nifr, when deploy in production:.  on-deploy:
    - symfony2/assets-install: { env: prod }
    - symfony2/assetic-dump: { env: prod }
    - symfony2/cache-clear: { env: prod }

Comment: form action="#". In dev action /login_check in pro #. i generate url:{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}     why???

Comment: can't follow - you need to be more concrete with your description ... i generate url, why? ... sorry can't help you if you don't provide more details what exactly you're doing, where you deploy and what exactly you see when you try to login.... So you're using magellanes to deploy ... which symfony version ... form action ?! honestly i can't guess everything :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you imported FOSUserBundle's routing in `routing_dev.yml` instead of `routing.yml`.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Clear your production cache after any change to routing!

```
app/console cache:clear --env="prod"
```

You can check wether the route is correctly registered in `prod` environment with:

```
app/console router:debug --env="prod"
```

Otherwise you don't generate the url for the form-action correctly.
This should be in your template:

```
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}">
```